# Access Skype db from data/app location

Tags: android, skype

I want to get the Skype db file, which is called main.db and is not encrypted like WhatsApp etc. and copy that file to my custom folder.
What I am trying to do is the following: (**my device is rooted and I am giving my app SuperUser access**)

```
public void getSkypeDB() throws InterruptedException
{
    Process sh;
    try
    {
        sh = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su", null, null);
        File skypeDir= new File("/data/app", "/com.skype.raider");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), skypeDir.toString(), 0).show();
        sh.waitFor();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

After doing this, my app crashed!

How can I get access to its database or access to the location of the database in the `/data/app` folder?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The database for an app won't be in `/data/app/<app_package_name>`, that's where the downloaded or pre-bundled APKs are located.  The runtime data directory for an app is at `/data/data/<app_package_name>`.  Also, be sure to include the stack trace from your exception catch or from the crash itself, otherwise it is a lot harder for people to help.

Comment: datbase will be in `/data/data/<app_package_name>/databases/main.db`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response :)
I will just try it now. and in case i get any error , i will surely post logs in future.

Comment: @sunny... there is not database folder ... :/
My device is rooted and i am checking it in root explorer...

Comment: It's a silly question, but has the Skype app actually been loaded and run on that device?

Comment: It's actually not that silly of a question.  You could have installed the app but never actually run it, so any runtime data managed by the app would not have been created. But, I hear what you are saying.  It may be helpful to provide everyone with a listing of what data is actually present in the data directory.  Older versions of Skype (circa 2011) would store the database in a subdirectory with the name of the user login.  I'm not sure what the latest version does, but without seeing a dir listing there's no way to guess.